# ANDROID - How to define ratingbar id in listview?

Tags: android, listview

I'm new in android and stack overflow, so I want to say sorry if I doing something wrong nor break the rule and for an idiot question!

I want to know how to define `ratingbar` in `listview` by id
I mean, how to know which `ratingbar` in the list is get the star?

I've been tried a tutorial from net, but its too hard to find the reference,
as far as I know, I need an implementation about `getView()` to get the `ratingBar` position, but I don't know how to add the code,

can someone help me out the issue?

Comment: some have an idea? please!

Comment: I just googled and found this https://www.raywenderlich.com/124438/android-listview-tutorial

Comment: @hadilq can you explain me what the function of `receipeAdapter` in above link? and why it should add `receipeAdapter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

- create a custom list view...
- custom adapter
- and handle rating bar in custom adapter.

Here is rating_bar_list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Food Rating"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is RatingListCustomAdapter.java

```
public class RatingListCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<String> ratingItemName;
Context context;
RatingListCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list){
    ratingItemName = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_bar_list_item, viewGroup, false);


    TextView itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    itemName.setText(ratingItemName.get(i).toString());
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

    ratingBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*...Here you can get which rating bar is clicked.. where i is the position of the rating bar in list */
        }
    });

    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
            //Here handle your rating bar clicked operation ... get id of clicked rating bar
            Log.d("rating_bar_clicked","Rating bar id: "+ratingBar.getId()+ " Value:"+String.valueOf(v));
        }
    });


    return v;
}
```

}

now in main just set the adapter to listview..

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(new RatingListCustomAdapter(this,itemNameList));
```

Comment: Wow, that's a nice code, but which code that i know about which ratingbar is clicked or not?

Comment: bro ... have a deep look ... i have comment in that function ..... in. .. RatingListCustomAdapter.java 
**getView()  onRatingChanged()** you can also define **ratingBar.setOnClickListner()** too

Comment: Ive looking out of your code above bro.. i mean its for `OnRatingChanged` is for code when rating change, i want to implement the code in button, i have a logic like ; when button clicked, it's will save any rating value in the list and send it to server,

Comment: yep you can also implement onClickListner() in the getView() function

Comment: sorry for late respone nightcoder, i still dont know about that `onClickListener()` function and how to implement in my code, it's for saved the ratingBar which getting star or not?

Comment: no problem ! check out the updated answer ,,, I have updated the getView() function in **RatingListCustomAdapter**

Comment: bro, when i want to try your code above in new project, it's give me an error on this code `R.layout.rating_bar_list_item` that tell me cannot resolve the rating_bar_list_item.xml, but i did created rating_bar_list_item inside layout folder, what happend?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below link which demonstrates your requirement of working with a rating bar inside a listView.

http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/rating-bar-in-listview-android.html

Comment: I've been read above link and [this link](http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-vote-rating-php-mysql.html) but the problem at above link is i have a TextView obtained from internet through json, and in my link, i don't need to create another layout to fill the rating, it's mean, i need above link work to online with json in arraylist, and in my link i dont need another layout,

Answer (score 0):

The adapter is designed to connect the Data to the View. If you know MVC, the adapter connects Model to View, as you can see it in this picture(https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2016/01/adapter.png) from that tutorial.

Why we should use adapters is because they make life easier. When you think about the "data", you don't need to think about the "view", just put your data into the adapter, and when you think about the "view", the adapter knows everything about the "data".